# use ILIKE ANY on values from a column in a different table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-like

Have a list of email domains and want to tag 'free' if the domain is like a free domain,
this works for me with a hard coded list like this:

```
CASE WHEN lower(email_domain) ilike any ('%%gmail%%','%%yahoo%%', '%%hotmail%%') THEN 'free' else 'business' end
```

but what I really want to do is get the list of free domains from a column in a diffrent table which looks something like this:

```
| SUBSTRING_VALUE   |
|:------------------|
| "gmail"           |
| "hotmail"         |
| "yahoo"           |
```

I've tried using a subquery with listagg or arrayagg, but it does not work,
any way of doing this?

Comment: You only need a single `%` BTW. You might find it easier to have the wildcard character '%' included in the lookup table so when you join your main table to it, you won't have to use `concat`. It also gives you the flexibility of placing the wildcard the way you want for individual values (leading, trailing, elsewhere)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
  CASE WHEN f.domain IS NOT NULL THEN 'free' ELSE 'business' END AS email_type
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN freedomain f
  ON t.email_domain ILIKE CONCAT('%', f.domain, '%');
```

Sidenote:
When ILIKE is used, there is no need to LOWER the email_domain column as comparison is already case-insensitive.

---

Sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE freedomain
AS
SELECT 'gmail' AS domain 
UNION SELECT 'yahoo'
UNION SELECT 'hotmail';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test
AS
SELECT 'biz' AS email_domain
UNION SELECT 'hotmail';
```

Output:

```
EMAIL_DOMAIN    EMAIL_TYPE
hotmail         free
biz             business
```

Answer (score 1):

Lukas answer is solid but to avoid have to add the wildcard tokens `%` to the domains, you can use [RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html) which is a "regexp like" like.

But it's is case sensitive in the default form, which you don't want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
  IFF( f.domain IS NOT NULL, 'free', 'busineess') AS email_type
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN freedomain f
  ON t.email_domain RLIKE f.domain;
```

so the second form needs to be used to add the insensitive flag `'i'`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
  IFF( f.domain IS NOT NULL, 'free', 'busineess') AS email_type
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN freedomain f
  ON RLIKE(t.email_domain , f.domain, 'i');
```

BUT it really to should not be making open both ended matches because `this.is.not.google.com.example.com` is a valid domain, and it's not `google.com`

thus your match should be a anchored or use [ENDSWITH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/endswith.html) (but again that is not case insensitive)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE freedomain AS 
    SELECT column1 as domain FROM VALUES 
        ('gmail.com'),
        ('yahoo.com'),
        ('hotmail.com') 
;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test AS
    SELECT column1 as email_domain FROM VALUES 
        ('mybiz.com'),
        ('thisisnotgmail.com.example.com'),
        ('gmail.com'),
        ('hotmail.com')
;
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
  IFF( f.domain IS NOT NULL, 'free', 'busineess') AS email_type
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN freedomain f
  ON RLIKE(t.email_domain , f.domain || '$', 'i');
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
  IFF( f.domain IS NOT NULL, 'free', 'busineess') AS email_type
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN freedomain f
  ON t.email_domain LIKE '%' || f.domain;
```

| EMAIL_DOMAIN | EMAIL_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| gmail.com | free |
| hotmail.com | free |
| mybiz.com | busineess |
| thisisnotgmail.com.example.com | busineess |